# "a única testemunha é uma prostituta" - Como podemos classificar esse artifício de retórica?

Tags: figuras-de-linguagem

**Contexto**

Durante um julgamento, o advogado de defesa dirige-se ao juiz.  "O meu cliente é inocente. Não há nada que o incrimine, nenhuma prova, e **a única testemunha apresentada pela promotoria é uma prostituta.**" Seria uma figura de linguagem ou um artifício de retórica?  Que figura ou que artifício?

Comment: Podes indicar a fonte? Provavelmente não é artifício de retórica. Creio que a maioria dos juízes desvalorizariam o testemunho duma prostituta.

Comment: Não há uma fonte.  Eu inventei um contexto. Posso inventar outro  "Ora, eu não vou admitir que uma menina de 10 anos, que não sabe nada da vida, venha me dizer o que é certo ou errado"   (dito por um homem de 50 anos que foi advertido por uma menina ao tentar furar a fila. ("jump the queue")

Comment: [_ad hominem_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem)?

Comment: @Artefacto  Ataque ao homem?  Sim, parece ser.  Qual das sub-classes seria?

Comment: @Luis, o que acha desse? https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envenenando_o_po%C3%A7o

Comment: @toliveira Perfeito.  É a resposta.

Comment: O nome geral disso é [falácia](https://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falácia).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É um ataque [ad-hominem](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_hominem).

Mais especificamente, é um "argumento *ad hominem* abusivo": em que se ataca a reputação do arguente em vez de se atacar a força dos seus argumentos em si.

---

Alguns dos outros tipos seriam:

- Circunstancial - a parcialidade de alguém não implica a falsidade dos seus argumentos (um padre diz que o seu deus existe, "claro, senão não tinha emprego");
- *Tu quoque* - não é por eu não praticar o que digo que isso deixa de ser verdade (um fumador que aconselhe alguém a deixar de fumar);
- Culpa por associação - não é por haver outrem de mau caráter que defende a mesma coisa que os meus argumentos são inválidos; um caso particular disto é o [*reductio ad Hitlerum*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_Hitlerum): "Sabes quem também era anti-tabagista? O Hitler!!"

Comment: Muito bom. Há quem também chame de Ad Hominem circunstancial, sub-divisão "Envenenando o Poço".